Swiper JS playbutton disappear after observer
It only happens on mobile devices.
Situation on mobile:

The user plays a video.
The user scrolls to another carousel video, and the intersection observer triggers, playing the second video.
The user navigates back to the first video via intersection, but the
play button is missing.
The user touches the mobile screen and
swipes slightly forward or backward, and the play button appears.
The user releases their finger, and the play button disappears.

Expected: The play button should always be visible if the video is stopped. This behavior works on desktop but not on touchscreens.
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const iframesWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName("video-wrapper");
  let currentPlayingIndex = null;
  const players = [];
  const videoStates = {};

  const isMultiplePlayback = document.getElementById("dataBlock").getAttribute("data-allow-multiple-playback");

  const observerOptions = {
    root: document.getElementById("swiperCarousel"),
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.3,
  };

  const intersectionCallback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const index = entry.target.dataset.index;
      const videoElement = document.getElementById(`video-${index}`);
      const playButton = document.getElementById(`playButton-${index}`);
      const overlay = videoElement.querySelector(".overlay");
      const iframe = videoElement.querySelector("iframe");

      if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
        if (iframe.src.includes("autoplay=true")) {
          playButton.style.display = "none";
          overlay.style.display = "block";
        }
      } else {
        if (videoStates[index] === "stopped") {
          let src = iframe.src;
          if (src.includes("autoplay=true")) {
            src = src.replace("autoplay=true", "");
            iframe.src = src;
          }

          playButton.style.display = "block";
          overlay.style.display = "none";
          Stream(iframe).pause();
        } else if (iframe.src.includes("autoplay=true")) {
          playButton.style.display = "none";
          overlay.style.display = "block";
          Stream(iframe).pause();
        } else if (videoStates[index] === "playing") {
          playButton.style.display = "none";
          overlay.style.display = "block";
          Stream(iframe).play();
        } else {
          playButton.style.display = "block";
          overlay.style.display = "none";
          Stream(iframe).pause();
          console.log("pause");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback, observerOptions);

  Array.from(iframesWrappers).forEach((videoElement, index) => {
    videoElement.dataset.index = index;
    const videoUrl = videoElement.dataset.url;

    const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = videoUrl;
    iframe.style.transform = "scale(1.02)";
    iframe.style.width = "100%";
    iframe.style.height = "100%";
    iframe.style.border = "none";
    iframe.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    iframe.style.position = "absolute";
    iframe.style.top = "0";
    iframe.allow =
      "accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share";

    videoElement.style.position = "relative";
    videoElement.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    videoElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
    videoElement.appendChild(iframe);

    const overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.classList.add("overlay");
    overlay.style.position = "absolute";
    overlay.style.top = "0";
    overlay.style.left = "0";
    overlay.style.width = "100%";
    overlay.style.height = "100%";
    overlay.style.cursor = "pointer";
    overlay.style.zIndex = "1";

    const playButton = document.getElementById(`playButton-${index}`);

    if (videoUrl.includes("autoplay=true")) {
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      playButton.style.display = "none";
      currentPlayingIndex = index;
      videoStates[index] = "playing";
    } else {
      overlay.style.display = "none";
      playButton.style.display = "block";
      videoStates[index] = "stopped";
    }

    videoElement.appendChild(overlay);

    Stream(iframe).addEventListener("ended", () => {
      playButton.style.display = "block";
      overlay.style.display = "none";
      videoStates[index] = "stopped";
    });

    const player = Stream(iframe);
    players[index] = player;

    observer.observe(videoElement);

    playButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (isMultiplePlayback === "false") {
        if (currentPlayingIndex !== index && currentPlayingIndex !== null) {
          const prevPlayer = players[currentPlayingIndex];
          const prevVideoElement = document.getElementById(`video-${currentPlayingIndex}`);
          const prevPlayButton = document.getElementById(`playButton-${currentPlayingIndex}`);
          const prevOverlay = prevVideoElement.querySelector(".overlay");

          prevPlayButton.style.display = "block";
          prevOverlay.style.display = "none";

          if (prevPlayer) {
            prevPlayer.pause();
            videoStates[currentPlayingIndex] = "stopped";
          }
        }
      }

      currentPlayingIndex = index;
      player.play();
      iframe.style.display = "block";
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      playButton.style.display = "none";
      videoStates[index] = "playing";
    });

    overlay.addEventListener("click", () => {
      player.pause();
      playButton.style.display = "block";
      overlay.style.display = "none";
      videoStates[index] = "stopped";
      currentPlayingIndex = null;
    });
  });
});

I also have swiper settings:
const swiperElement = document.querySelector("#swiperCarousel");

if (swiperElement) {
  const totalSlides = swiperElement.querySelectorAll(".swiper-slide").length;

  let slidesPerView = null;
  let loop = true;

  if (totalSlides == 3) {
    slidesPerView = 2.3;
  } else if (totalSlides == 2) {
    slidesPerView = 1.9;
    loop = false;
  }

  let breakpoints = {
    481: { slidesPerView: totalSlides >= 4 ? 3.125 : slidesPerView },
    320: { slidesPerView: 1.1 },
  };

  new Swiper("#swiperCarousel", {
    loop: loop,
    slidesPerView: slidesPerView,
    centeredSlides: false,
    spaceBetween: 8,
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    breakpoints: breakpoints,
  });
}

I'm using HTML:
import { useBlockProps } from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import PlayButtonSvg from "../assets/PlayButtonSvg";
import PlayButton from "../assets/Vector.png";

const Save = ({ attributes }) => {
  const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
  return (
    <>
      <script src="https://embed.cloudflarestream.com/embed/sdk.latest.js"></script>

      <div {...blockProps} id="dataBlock" data-allow-multiple-playback={attributes.allowMultiplePlayback}>
        <div id="swiperCarousel" className="swiper">
          <div className="swiper-wrapper">
            {attributes.videos.map((video, index) => (
              <div className="swiper-slide" key={index}>
                <div className="video-wrapper" id={`video-${index}`} data-url={video.videoUrl}>
                  <img className="playButtonFull" id={`playButton-${index}`} src={PlayButton} alt="play button" />
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Save;

I checked on the dev tools it has display: block, but not visible.
